# Aggregate shows null value

Tags: c#, linq

My lambda expression:

```
lst.Add(qry.Where(item => item.Type == "Gundalac")
           .Aggregate(new CDetails(), (accumulator, item) => new CDetails {
                       Des = "CATALOG", 
                       Amt = accumulator.Amt + item.Amt 
                   }));

public class CDetails
{   
    public string Des { get; set; }
    public decimal? Amt { get; set; }
}
```

Always the `Amt` is null value? How to get the total of Amount for the results on "qry".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would check that `qry.Where(item => item.Type == "Gundalac")` actually returns any items.

Once you check that I'd be inclined to change your code to this:

```
lst.Add(new CDetails()
{
    Des = "CATALOG", 
    Amt = qry
        .Where(item => item.Type == "Gundalac")
        .Sum(item => item.Amt)
});
```

In this particular case using `.Sum()` is a lot simpler.